# Unable to resolve filesystem path when trying to access Documents folder in a physical device with ionic/capacitor

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am developing a function to catch and read KML files, and another function to unzip and save these files that are inside of KMZ files (basically a zip).

In the first attempt I could not access it because an error told me that I don't have de right permissions, but according to [capacitor documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/android/configuration) and after add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, I could obtain the right permission to access the device files. After that I had to filter the URI using the function `FilePath.resolveNativePath(path);` from the [FilePath](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path). The original path is generated by `fileChooser.open().then(uri=>{})` and the URI is the root path to the file.

After some tests with an Android emulator using API 29/v10 and API 30/v11 and then a physical Android device with API 29/v10, I was able to make the functions work, but in physical device there is a specific folder, Documents, that is inaccessible and generate a error:

> "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"code":0,"message":"Unable to resolve filesystem path."}".

### **Page.ts:**

```js
selectFile(): Promise<void>{
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        return this.fileChooser.open().then(uri => {
            return this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri).then(uri => {
                let filename = uri.split('/').pop();
                this.layerName = filename;
                this.fileURI = uri;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

### **Edits**

URI before the edition : `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/home%3Apoligono.kml`.

URI after the edition : error occurs after run the function FilePath.resolveNativePath(uri);. This happens only in this specific folder, in the physical device.

### **Folder Documents:**

[image: Folder Documents]

Comment: Tell the values of mentioned uri and path to begin with.

Comment: If you select from Documents you are served by a media provider. If you select from primary:Documents or secundary:Documents you are served by external storage provider. And `.resolveNativePath(uri)` cannot handle the first one.

Comment: But... It is a bad habit trying to convert such a nice uri to a file system path. You should not do such nasty things.

Comment: I updated this information in the main question.

Comment: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/home%3Apoligono.kml.` That is a little bit different then usual. It is from the external storage provider but it uses that `home` for Documents folder. I've seen this before. But not on modern devices. As it is so rare `resolveNativePath(uri)` is unaware of it and cannot resolve. You now know who you have to blame.

Comment: I'm converting the content:// to file:/// using resolveNativePath(), because with content://  some errors of permission and not found directory occurs. I have to make this conversion to bypass this errors and access the device storage. How do you do the manual conversion?

Comment: `because with content:// some errors of permission and not found directory occurs. ` Well there is no reason why that should happen. Not for permissions and not for directories as the uri is for a file and as such has nothing to do with directories.